# How do you split PCollections by some criterion?

Tags: python, apache-beam

How do you split a PCollection by some evaluation?

Lets say I have:

```
  messages = (gcp | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=None, subscription=SUBSCRIPTION, with_attributes=True))
```

Now I want to split messages into two PCollections:

```
  split = messages | beam.Split(function())
```

split would be an array of PCollections, split by what is defined in my function.

I cannot find anything that does this, except partition, but that seemingly just splits it into buckets arbitrarily, without having some function to determine what goes where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that partition is indeed what you are wanting.  If we look at the Partition function documented close to [Core Beam Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms) (4.2.6) we find that the transformation takes as input:

- A function to determine which partition the element in the PCollection should be placed into.
- A count of the number of partitions to be used.

The function is called once for each of the elements in the PCollection and returns a numeric index of which of the partitions to place that element into.  For example, if you have two output possibilities then the number of partitions you would want would be two.  Your function would then be called for each element and an expression evaluated against each element.  If the expression is true return 0 to place that element in the first partition if the expression is false, return 1 to place that element in the second partition.  You have now split your PCollection into two distinct partitions governed by the nature of your function's logic.